# keep custom changes to index.html when using the automatic page generator in GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I used GitHub's automatic page generator to create an `index.html` file. Any time I make changes to the `README.md` file I use the automatic page generator to update `index.html`.

I would like to be able to add some custom code/HTML to the `index.html` file in the `head` section that will stick and say every time I use the automatic page generator. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: How exactly do you use the automatic page generator to update your `index.html`? I was pretty sure that was only for initially creating your page...

Comment: I just redo it every time I make changes to my README.md.

Comment: Where is the content of your `index.html` coming from? It may be possible to simply put that in another file (such as `README.md`) and have GitHub Pages automatically paste it into your `index.html` every time something changes.

Comment: It comes from my `README.md` file. The Automatic Page Generator will let you load a `README.md` file and it uses that to dynamically generate `index.html`. So every time you use the APG it will overwrite `index.html`. How would I have GitHub automatically paste it into my `index.html` every time something changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`include`](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#including-files-relative-to-another-file) your `README.md` somewhere in your `index.html` using [Jekyll](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/), which is just for this purpose.

`index.html`:

```
---
---
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>

    <body>
        {% include_relative README.md %}
    </body>
</html>
```

should work nicely for you. Feel free to add any other content you need to the "template". To get the theme from the GitHub Pages generator, you can probably just open your current `index.html` and copy it out, replacing all your content with the `include` tag.